# The sum of an zipfile archive's parts is not equal to its file size

Tags: python, archive

**TL;DR** - The actual problem is that I am working on something that provides information about the entries in an archive file and specifies 'where' the size in the archive is coming from. The example below is sort of exactly not like my real problem(which has hundreds of thousands of entries) but highlights the actual problem I'm running into. My problem is that there's a non-trivial amount of size in my archive that is unaccounted for (actually used in the overhead for compression is my guess). The sum of the parts of my archive (the total compressed size of all of my entries + the expected gaps between them) is less than the actual size of the archive. How do I inspect the archive in a way that provides insight into this hidden overhead?

**Where I'm at:**

I have a directory that contains three files:

1. `doc.pdf`
2. `cat.jpg`
3. `model.stl`

Using a freeware program I dump these into a zip file: `demo.zip`

Using python I can inspect these pretty easily:

```
info_list= zipfile.ZipFile('demo.zip').infolist()
for i in info_list:
    print i.orig_filename
    print i.compress_size
    print i.header_offset
```

Using this info we can get some info.

The total size of demo.zip is 84469

The compressed size of:

```
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|
|      File           | Compressed Size | Header Offset |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|
|         doc.pdf     |       21439     |       0       |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|
|         cat.jpg     |       48694     |    21495      |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|
|       model.stl     |       13870     |    70232      |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|
```

I know that zipping will result in some space between entries. (Thus the difference between the sums of previous entry sizes and the header offset for every entry). You can calculate this small 'Gap':

```
gap = offset - previous_entry_size - previous_entry_offset
```

I can update my chart to look like:

```
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|---------------|
|      File           | Compressed Size | Header Offset |     'Gap'     |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|---------------|
|         doc.pdf     |       21439     |       0       |       0       |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|---------------|
|         cat.jpg     |       48694     |    21495      |       56      |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|---------------|
|       model.stl     |       13870     |    70232      |       43      |
|---------------------|-----------------|---------------|---------------|
```

Cool. So now one might expect that the size of demo.zip would be equal to the sum of the size of all entries and their gaps. (84102 in the example above).

But that's not the case. So, obviously, zipping requires headers and information about how zipping occurred (and how to unzip). But I'm running into a problem on **how** to define this or access any more information about it.

I could just take 84469 - 84102 and say ~magic zip overhead~ = 367 bytes. But that seems less than ideal because this number obviously is not magic. Is there a way to inspect the underlying zip data that is taking up this space?

Comment: Isn't that a question about the PKZip data format in particular rather than a Python question?

Comment: I had debated using a nonsensical zip format for this reason. The same problem exists for most / all archive formats I've explored. ZipFile does't seem to give data about the things I need but it obviously has to 'know' about it otherwise how could it report on entries in the zip file?

Comment: A good start to figuring it out would be by reading the [`zipfile` source](https://hg.python.org/cpython/file/2.7/Lib/zipfile.py). (There should also be a copy installed in your `Python/Lib` directory—be careful not to accidentally change it!)  In addition there's the [**_APPNOTE.TXT - .ZIP File Format Specification_**](https://pkware.cachefly.net/webdocs/casestudies/APPNOTE.TXT).

Comment: @Nahkki But the `zipfile` module is not intended as a data format dissector. It's for getting files into and out of an archive. That suffices for purely _using_ PKZip files. Apparently you want to go beyond that, which is beyond the module's scope, even if its implementation knows about the internals.

Comment: Still, reading the package source is likely to be the most efficient way of gaining insight on the internals short of just reading the file format specifications.

Answer (score 0):

An empty zip file is [22 bytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#Limits), containing only the End of Central Directory Record.

```
In [1]: import zipfile

In [2]: z = zipfile.ZipFile('foo.zip', 'w')

In [3]: z.close()

In [4]: import os

In [5]: os.stat('foo.zip').st_size
Out[5]: 22
```

If the zip-file is not empty, for every file you have a central directory file [header](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Zip_(file_format)#File_headers) (at least 46 bytes), and a local file header (at least 30 bytes).

The actual headers have a *variable length* because the given lengths do not include space for the file name which is part of the header.